# How can I initialize a State Var in Swift UI without getting the error "Cannot use instance member 'XXX' within property initializer;"

Tags: ios, swiftui, cllocationmanager, swift5, observedobject

I am looking to put a users location on a MapView and have the location update as the user moves. I am using an @observedObject Var for the class handling the location manager stuff and a @state Var for the MKCoordinateRegion() Class. However I am running into an issue where if I put the declaration for the @observedObject var before declaring and defining the @state var I come to the error

*("Cannot use instance member 'latitude' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available")*

I have seen other people post this issue and I have tried an .init() function as well as using a lazy var. However the issue comes in to play that the @state var needs to be of type MKCoordinateRegion() and hence needs to be initialized with values. My root for not understanding how to fix this is most likely not understanding the timeline for how views are loaded since ive only ever worked with UIBuilder and not SwiftUI. Any help would be appreciated!

```
struct MapView: View {
    @ObservedObject var usersLocation = LocationManager()
    var latitude: Double{ return((usersLocation.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0))}
    var longitude: Double{ return((usersLocation.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0))}
    @State var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude , longitude: longitude),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
    )
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
            .onAppear()
        Text(String(latitude));
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the values of the properties depend on each other and you cannot declare them this way.

But you can implement an `init` method

```
struct MapView: View {
    @ObservedObject var usersLocation : LocationManager
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    @State var region : MKCoordinateRegion

    init(manager : LocationManager) {
        self.usersLocation = manager
        let lat = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0
        self.latitude = lat
        let long = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0
        self.longitude = long
        let reg = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat , longitude: long),
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
        )
        self._region = State<MKCoordinateRegion>(initialValue: reg)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
            .onAppear()
        Text(String(latitude));
    }
    
}
```

and pass the `LocationManager` in the parent view and declare it there as `@StateObject`

```
@StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
...
MapView(manager: locationManager)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes perfect sense now. I had tried using an init() function. But I was unaware of the functionality of passing a manager as well as declaring a @stateobject in the calling view. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use something like this:

```
struct MapView: View {
    @ObservedObject var usersLocation = LocationManager()
    @State var latitude: Double = 0.0
    @State var longitude: Double = 0.0
    @State var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
            .onAppear {
                latitude = (usersLocation.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0.0)
                longitude = (usersLocation.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0.0)
                region = MKCoordinateRegion(
                    center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude , longitude: longitude),
                    span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
            }
    }
}
```